# Boundary for position: absolute

Tags: html, css, position, boundary

I'm trying to add hover boxes to elements. They contain some content, have a fixed width, but not height. The height depends on the content.

Now the problem is, that if I try to position the top-left corner right from the element I'm hovering, and the element is at the bottom of the screen, the hover box goes out of the screen bounds. I need some way to check if the bottom of the element is below the screen, then I want to position the bottom-left corner at the bottom of the hovered element. Is that possible using only CSS? Or do I need to use JavaScript for that calculation?

Comment: Could you provide minimum reproducible code for your problem ?https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: YOu need JS for it. Alternatively the `title`-attribute might be of help.

Comment: @SachinSom I can't really do that, because the example I'm trying to do is way too big. But I fixed the problem using JavaScript now!